# Groovy Jira Rest API NoSuchFieldError: defaultRequestContentType

Tags: groovy, jira, rest-client

This is my first step working with Jira Rest API and I will only return simple `serverInfo`

Here is my Groovy Script:

```
def jira = new RESTClient(JIRAURL + "/rest/api/2/");
jira.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
jira.headers['Authorization']="Basic " + "username:password".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
println  jira.get(path:'serverInfo')
```

If I execute my script I get this Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultRequestContentType
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.<init> 
(HTTPBuilder.java:989)
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError" is probably because of

```
jira.headers[...
```

Have you tried to set these default headers with methods e.g.

```
jira.setHeaders([Content-Type: "......"])
jira.setHeaders([Authorization: "Basic ....."])
```

or

```
jira.httpClient.defaultHeaders['Content-Type'] = '...' 
jira.httpClient.defaultHeaders['Authorization'] = '...'
```

The JIRA Rest call call looks fine and you can test it with Postman to check that issue is not with JIRA itself.